# How do I access a prototype TableViewCell in another TableViewController on the same storyboard

Tags: xcode4, xcode-storyboard, ios5

I have several TableViewControllers that have exactly the same format TableViewCell used for completely different purposes.  I have a TableViewController that has all of my prototype cells defined in it including different format records and different reuse types.

My question is how do I set up each of the TableViewControllers and TableViewCells in the Scene that I am going to use a particular Prototype TableViewCell.

All I have seen is documentation on one TableViewController with One Prototype TableViewController but I do not want to have to prototype the same cell all of the times I need to use it. It seems to go against the nature of the technology.

So I guess I am asking how to set up the TableViewCcontroller and the Associated TableViewCell in StoryBoard so that they will use the prototype that I have defined elsewhere on my StoryBoard.